# AWS EC2 SSH short lived

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am using AWS EC2, up to yesterday everything seems to work fine. but today when I logged in to EC2 via SSH, the session is short lived.

It shows `connection closed` after 3-4 seconds of inactivity.

How can I check what happened, am I under some hacking attack or something? because I haven't changed anything.

> How to fix this?

also tried below command no effect

`echo 'ClientAliveInterval 60' | sudo tee --append /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am asking how to fix this, as I tried some options already. So this can be placed under stackoverflow.

Comment: did you find anything in your ec2 instance logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a client issue.

edit - `~/.ssh/config`

```
# This is ~/.ssh/config
# For all hosts
ServerAliveInterval 10

# For a selection of hosts
Host keepsdroppingme.com alsokeepsdroppingme.com
  ServerAliveInterval 10
```